# Regular expression with limit to number of characters

Tags: regex, regex-group, elasticsearch-dsl

I need to be able to match all strings that should start with either of the words "dog", "frog" or "elephant" and the remaining should be numbers [0-9]. The maximum length of the string should be 10 characters.

eg: dog1234567, frog123456, elephant12 etc

I have tried ((dog|frog|elephant)[0-9]+){10} but this matches the whole thing 10 times.

Comment: sorry for the wrong tag. i need this for an elasticsearch query. so i cannot use any functions

Answer (score 1):

You could use an alternation matching the word followed by digits where the total is 10 characters.

On [this page](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/regexp-syntax.html#:%7E:text=A%20regular%20expression%20is%20a,regexp) it states that the engine does not support anchors and has to match the whole string.

```
(dog[0-9]{7}|frog[0-9]{6}|elephant[0-9]{2})
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DFg7lK/1).